# Loading library with QLibrary

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries, qlibrary

I found the following code for loading libraries in Qt but I do not fully understand how it works. Could someone explain to me from: `typedef int (*MyPrototype)(int, int);`?

```
int r1 = 0;
QLibrary library("mathlib.so");
    if (!library.load())
        out << library.errorString() << endl;
    if (library.load())
        out << "library loaded" << endl;

    typedef int (*MyPrototype)(int, int);

    MyPrototype myFunction = (MyPrototype)library.resolve("add");
    if (myFunction)
        r1 = myFunction(a,b);
    else
        out << library.errorString() << endl;
```

Comment: Its a pointer to a function.

Comment: So I would have to do this for every function I want to call?

Comment: Yes, you will have to.

Comment: So my only other option will be to have all the header files available when using the library in an aplication?

Comment: You can generate .lib files if you have the dll.

Comment: How do i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so or dll has function and we want to use it, so how we can call it

```
int add(int in_iParam1, int in_iParam2)
```

define function type

```
typedef int (*MyPrototype)(int, int);
```

looking for function 'add' in so file

```
MyPrototype myFunction = (MyPrototype)library.resolve("add");
```

Call function 'add' with parameters 'a' and 'b' and get result to 'r1'

```
r1 = myFunction(a,b);
```

Comment: An does the definition of the Prototype represent anything specific?

Comment: It should contain same types as in function what you will call

Comment: OK, But I was referring to the actual name given to the definition of the function: MyPrototype?

Comment: Yes, in function type definition you can use any name